# Getting entities of a certain type using entity frameworks return error - LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Type GetType()'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities, gettype

I am trying to filter out entities of a certain type. I am using Entity Framework, and I have a parent entity, and various children that inherit from the parent entity. I am trying to filter out one of these children.

For example, I have the following structure:

- Address : Entity

  - PostCode : Address
  - Street : Address

A User entity has a reference to one address. How can I obtain a list of users that are associated to an address of type PostCode?

i.e. I tried:

```
 var query = from User p in context.Users
                        where p.Address.GetType() == typeof(PostCode)
                        select p;
```

But I get:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Type GetType()'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I have seen couple of solutions that involve obtaining the list of Users first, and then selecting those of a certain type. Problem with this solution is that the query obtains all the users first; I would like my query to include the filter since I have quite a few Users.

Thanks!

Comment: Wait. User has only one address? So it can have only either PostCode or Street? Isn't that wrong?

Comment: well, I have made up this example for simplicity. Probably not the best example, but yes, it can only have a PostCode or a Street.

Comment: Try to use `p.Address is PostalCode`

Comment: that did the job! Add it as an answer ;)

Comment: On another note, once you obtain the list of users with PostCode as address, and you select one of the users, can you cast its address to a PostCode? Or is there a better way of obtaining the PostCode object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using is operator.

```
 var query = from User p in context.Users
                    where p.Address is PostCode
                    select p;
```

Comment: Could you give me an example? Note that the User is not associated to the type of address. from User p in context.Users where p.Address.OfType ... ? That doesnt seem to work

Comment: on another note, when I get the list of Users, and I select one of them (myUser) - how can I obtain the PostCode object. i.e. PostCode p = myUser.Address  (that wouldnt work, maybe casting? or is there a better way?)

Comment: Euphoric's original solution doesn't work. It throws the following error, "The specified type member 'Address' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

Comment: @spadelives I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere else in the code. Is Address a property?

Comment: Yes, the address is a property. It doesn't work because such a statement cannot be translated in SQL.